# CSS height в % не работает?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Почему, когда в height пишешь в px всё нормально, а когда в процентах, как на рисунке, ничего не работает?
height в процентах нельзя делать?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="home_page.js"></script>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="accaunt.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            body.style_body {
                background-attachment: scroll;
                background-clip: border-box;
                background-origin: padding-box;
                direction: ltr;
                display: block;
                margin: 0px auto;
                overflow: scroll;
                padding: 0px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .gods_area {
                background: #d954ff;
                border-bottom: 2px solid black;
                height: 82%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 10000;
            }
        </style>
        <title>School.ua</title>
    </head>
    <body class="style_body">
        <div id="gods_area" class="gods_area"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если вы берете проценты, их нужно брать от чего то
Т.е. либо пропишите, как сказано выше

```
body, html{height:100%}
```

либо укажите в родительском элементе тоже самое

```
body.style_body { height:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Конечно 100% можно использовать, но я бы вам советовал использовать так называемые viewport меры. (vh, vw, vmin, vmax)

```css
body {
margin:0;
}
div {
background: #0af;
height:100vh;
color:white;
font-size:40px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
100 высота
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не хватает только прописать `body, html{height:100%}`.

Answer (score -3):

Стереть можно`<!DOCTYPE html>`, у меня так получилось.

Comment: гугл Хром)

Comment: так ты мой код посмотри

Comment: Сотри самую первую строчку  < ! D O C T Y P E h t m l > ;)

Comment: @Draculidze, чем вам доктайп не угодил?

Comment: @ling +1)
Какая разница?

Comment: Без doctype у меня заработало, не указывая в родительском элементе процентов :)

Comment: @Draculidze, doctype надо прописывать **всегда**, чтобы не было разногласий в разных браузерах. И код надо писать под выбранный доктайп. Проще всего с doctype html - доктайпом html5: он короткий и универслаьный.

Comment: Только этой дряни и не хватало. Добро пожаловать в IE 5.5! Доктайп должен быть.

Comment: ору с ответа конечно

Comment: кто использует 5.5 осла?

Comment: @ishidex2, любой осёл становится 5.5 если нет доктайпа.